# basic remote file move action in terminal doesn't work

Tags: command-line, ssh

I am remotely helping someone setup a linux nas (WD cloud) which is attached to a win10 machine via router. I connect from my ubuntu machine to the win10 via a teamviewer session and then ssh into the nas from there.
I placed a file x.ovpn into the Public folder:

```
/mnt/HD/HD_a2/Public/
```

directly from the windows machine as this is the only accessible folder from windows explorer.
I need to move this x.ovpn to:

```
/mnt/HD/HD_a2/Nas_Prog/Docker/Delugevpn/Config/
```

but when i try to move this file like this..

```
sudo mv /mnt/HD/HD_a2/Public/x.ovpn /mnt/HD/HD_a2/Nas_Prog/Docker/Delugevpn/Config/x.ovpn
```

I get an error that the file x.ovpn in Public doesn't exist, never the less it shows when list the files in that dir.

I have been able to move x.ovpn out of public into HD_a2 via `mv x.ovpn ../`, and that worked so now it is in HD_a2 but when i try to move it from there i get the same error.

i also tried there to make it simpler from within HD_a2 with.

```
sudo mv x.ovpn /mnt/HD/HD_a2/Nas_Prog/Docker/Delugevpn/Config/x.ovpn
```

or

```
sudo mv x.ovpn /Nas_Prog/Docker/Delugevpn/Config/x.ovpn
```

imho all three tasks should work, never the less i again got the answer the file doesn't exists.

the error message i recieved is.

```
mv: can't rename 'lu-ste_tcp.ovpn': No such file or directory
```

anyone any thoughts on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: [Edit] your post and show us the exact (cut and paste) error messages.

Comment: File names in Linux systems are case sensitive so for example `lu-ste_tcp.ovpn` is a different file name from `Lu-ste_tcp.ovpn`. Have you confirmed that what you typed after `mv` is the same case as the file name you want to move?

Comment: yes i did check this, unfortunately, just as well as the spelling. I did ddouble check just now. would have been nice if that was the answer but no.